# Div Columns With Full Fill on Height

Tags: html, css, height

I have a `div`(container). In it I put `div`s that should be arranged on y not on x as normally.

I'll attach an image to explain better:
[image]

I tried with `display: table-cell`, with `float` but no solution. What to do?

I don't have a fixed number of columns, I want them to be filled on `height`, and on `width` to go right until reach `#mydiv` width limit, then `display: none`.

```html
<ul class="prod_ul">


<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>
<li data-gal="" class="hm_gal"></li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ??

Comment: no, i don't want bootstrap

Comment: You can use `flexbox` to achieve what you want. Please add a starting point in code in order to properly answer your question.

Comment: yes, Roy is right. use flex. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: done @Roy i added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexbox` is useful here, while you can set the `flex-direction` to `column` to make it work *vertically*. See the code snippet below for a demo.

You can set the width and heights of the `.box` to any size and it will try to fill the space up. Read more about the `flexbox` property and how to use it at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#mydiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
   <div class="box">1</div>
   <div class="box">2</div>
   <div class="box">3</div>
   <div class="box">4</div>
   <div class="box">5</div>
   <div class="box">6</div>
   <div class="box">7</div>
   <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you achieve this with `column-count`?

This is normally what I would use:

```
.prod_ul {
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
}
```

Give that style to your parent `div` or `ul`, and it creates columns, just as you'd expect.